# Meter php dentro de una variable

Tags: php, html, ajax

Buenas estoy intentado meter foreach dentro de una variable para que me imprima el AJAX pero sin resultado alguno

```
include "../conexion/conecta.php";
$html = "";
if ($_POST["elegido"]==263) {

 $poblacion = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM barrio");
 foreach ($poblacion as $pobl){
  $id = $pobl['barrio_id'];
  $barrio = $pobl['barrio'];

    $html = '
    <option value="'$id'">"'$barrio'"</option>
    ';
}
}
echo $html;
```

Comment: que error te da? si lo haces por ajax como recibes el resultado?

Comment: Dicho código debería dar error de sintaxis, ya que cuando haces `$html = '
    <option value="'$id'">"'$barrio'"</option>
    ';` no es válido. Para concatenar variables y cadenas debes usar [punto (`.`)](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.string.php), así por ejemplo, `$html = '
    <option value="'.$id.'">"'.$barrio.'"</option>
    ';`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Marcos , abajo esta la solución completa, que es lo mismo que comentas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás sobre-escribiendo la variable $html una y otra vez

```
include "../conexion/conecta.php";
$html = "";
if ($_POST["elegido"]==263) {
  $poblacion = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM distrito");
  foreach ($poblacion as $pobl) {
    $id = $pobl['distrito_id'];
    $distrito = $pobl['distrito'];
    $html .= "<option value=\"$id\">$distrito</option>";
  }
}
echo $html;
```

Un pequeño (.) antes del operador (=) de la variable $html dentro del foreach es el añadido.

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias, solicionado de este modo, solo hay un problema, que si selecciono un select para que me muestre el siguiente, selecciono el siguiente y luego en el primero cambio la opción, no me cambia el segundo automaticamente, tengo que pulsarle @Ivan Miranda

Comment: @miguel no te entendi. Puedes elaborarlo más? Saludos

Comment: Hola! Si selecciono el primero se me muestra en el siguiente la información que corresponde, si selecciono una opción en ese segundo select y vuelvo al primero y cambio la opción ese segundo tendria que volver a su posición habitual pero no es asi @Ivan Miranda

Comment: ¿Donde te está dando esos problemas? Del lado del servidor o en la salida del HTML? @Miguel

Comment: En la parte del html!

Comment: @Miguel Puedes hacer un jsfiddle con el resultado de html que te arroja el código, y comentarme ahi mismo que es lo que sucede para que pueda ver si efectivamente es un error de html o podría ser un problema con el foreach. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Lo resolvi así, **lo malo que solo me saca un resultado, no saca la lista entera de la bd**

```
include "../conexion/conecta.php";
$html = "";
if ($_POST["elegido"]==263) {

 $poblacion = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM distrito");
 foreach ($poblacion as $pobl){
  $id = $pobl['distrito_id'];
  $distrito = $pobl['distrito'];

    $html = "
    <option value=\"$id\">$distrito</option>
    ";
}
}
echo $html;
```

Comment: Para obtener la lista completa debes `concatenar` los resultados a la variable `$html`. Es decir, en el `foreach` debes usar `$html .= "
    <option value=\"$id\">$distrito</option>
    ";` (si prestas atención uso [el operador `.=`](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.string.php) para contatenar.

Answer (score 0):

El resultado que te devuelve `mysqli->query()` es de tipo [mysqli_result](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php). Asi que tendras que ir cogiendo fila a fila del resultado. Una forma de hacerlo es con while:

```
include "../conexion/conecta.php";
$html = "";
    if ($_POST["elegido"]==263) {

     $poblacion = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM barrio");

     while ($pobl = $poblacion->fetch_assoc()){

      $id = $pobl['barrio_id'];
      $barrio = $pobl['barrio'];

        $html = '
        <option value="'$id'">"'$barrio'"</option>
        ';
    }
}
echo $html;
```

Comment: mira mi solución por si es valida también? @Francisco Garrido